# Separate A Static NSString For Loading Into An Array

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, static, nsstring

So following Apple's DocInteraction Sample [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010052-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) I put a `static NSString` to define some preloaded documents.  Now I need to load them into an NSArray in the `viewDidLoad` method.  If I put it into a `for()` statement, it says "expression result unused", and I know I could solve it by using `documents[indexPath.row]`, but it's the viewDidLoad method.  So how do I forEach a static NSString for loading into the NSArray?

CODE (EDIT):

```
//Before @implementation

static NSString* documents[] =
{   @"Musette.pdf",
    @"Minore.pdf",
    @"Cantata.pdf",
    @"Finalé.pdf"
};
//In viewDidLoad

    if ( _icons == nil )
{        

    _icons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBezierPath * path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0, 324.0)
                                                     cornerRadius: 18.0];
    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i <= 4; i++){

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( CGSizeMake(200.0, 324.0) );

        // clear background
        [[UIColor clearColor] set];
        UIRectFill( CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 324.0) );

        // fill the rounded rectangle
        [path fill];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ClearImage.png"];

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        // put the image into our list
        [_icons addObject: image];
    }
}

[_gridView reloadData];
```

Comment: EDIT: Code now works perfectly thanks to Denis' suggestion.  Thanks to all who answered.

Comment: Odd that the code nowhere references your `documents` array.

Comment: I think it has something to do with apple's special documentWatcher class from the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C-arrays are not supported by the for-each modification of the for statement in Objective-C. So you have 2 choices here:

1. use ordinary for-statement cycle

   for(int idx = 0; idx < KNOWN_DOCUMENTS_COUNT; ++idx) {
       ...
   }
2. Create a custom subclass of the NSEnumerator and use it... however, I believe, this will be a big overhead for this case

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you.  I will checkmark as soon as that dastardly time limit is through.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking completely:

```
for(NSString * myStr in _icons) {
```

This won't work because _icons == nil.  Why can't you create the strings before this line?

You also need to make this an NSArray.

Comment: Denis' answer was what I was looking for, thanks for the critique though!

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense whatsoever:

```
if ( _icons == nil )
    {        
        for(NSString * myStr in _icons) {

        _icons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You need to step back a bit and understand what you're doing.

### Added

Still doesn't work.  What's wrong with this picture??

```
    _icons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBezierPath * path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0, 324.0)
                                                     cornerRadius: 18.0];
                for(NSString * myStr in _icons) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( CGSizeMake(200.0, 324.0) );
```

Comment: Check the code now, totally a typo, as that would have initialized an array 4 times!

Comment: Would never have initialized the array at all.

Comment: OK, check the most recent edit... it has been solved... and what's with the down vote?